# Accessing an item in a dictionary in a list

Tags: python, list, dictionary, geolocation

I am currently working on a Visual trace route program in python (on Ubuntu). I am using pygeoip to get the coordinates (among other information). I am storing each IP's data in a list (listcoor). The problem I am having is accessing a specific dictionary item once it has been placed in the listcoor

```
def vargeolocating(matchob): # matchob is a list of IPs
    print "Geolocating IP addresses"
    gi = GeoIP.open("/usr/share/GeoIP/GeoLiteCity.dat",GeoIP.GEOIP_STANDARD)
    i = 0
    listcoor = []
    while ( i < len(matchob)):
        holder = gi.record_by_addr(matchob[i])
        if holder is None:# for local addresses
            print "None"
        else:       
            listcoor.append(holder) 
        i = i + 1 
    print holder['longitude'] # Prints out the last longitude
    print listcoor[12] # Prints all information about the last IP (this longitude matchs the above longitude
    print listcoor[12['longitude']] # Should print just the longitude, matching the two longitudes above
```

The last print displays an error "TypeError: 'int' object has no attribute '**getitem**'"

Comment: Separately, your loop can be simplified: `holder_iter = (gi.record_by_addr(m) for m in matchob); listcoor = [holder for holder in holder_iter if holder is not None]` or: `listcoor = filter(None, (gi.record_by_addr(m) for m in matchob))` if `gi.record_by_addr` gets an object or None.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to index `12`, but integers cannot be indexed; move the index syntax to index the *result* of the `12` index on `listcoor`:

```
listcoor[12]['longitude']
```

What is happening is this:

```
>>> 12['longitude']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'int' object is unsubscriptable
```